# close button malfunction (Extendscript)

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

Here is the whole script.

```
    UI();

    function UI() {

    var window = new Window ('dialog', 'Settings', undefined, {closeButton: true});
    window.orientation = 'column';

    var iFolderC = loadSettings (['I','F',0]);
    for (i = 1; i <= iFolderC; i++)
    eval('var ' + "iFolder" + i + " = loadSettings (['I','F'," + i + "]);");

    var inputGroup = window.add ('group');
    inputGroup.add('panel', undefined, 'Input Folders', {borderStyle:'raised'});
    inputGroup.orientation = 'column';
    //inputGroup.alignment = 'left';

    for (i = 1; i <= iFolderC; i++) {
    eval('var ' + "inputFolder" + i + "= inputGroup.add ('group');");
    eval("inputFolder" + i + ".add('panel', [0, 0, 300, 20], iFolder"+ i +", {borderStyle:'raised'});");
    eval('var ' + "removeButton" + i + "= inputFolder" + i + ".add ('button', undefined, 'Remove');");}

    var newFolder = inputGroup.add ('group');
    //var folderButton = newFolder.add("iconbutton", undefined, "#FolderOpened");
    var newIFolder = newFolder.add('edittext',[0, 0, 300, 20]);
    var addButton =  newFolder.add ('button', undefined, 'Add');
    addButton.onClick = function () {window.close(); saveSettings (['N', 'F', 0], newIFolder.text);}

    for (i = 1; i <= iFolderC; i++) {
    eval("removeButton" + i + ".onClick = function() {window.close(); saveSettings (['R', 'F'," + i + "], '');}");}

    var closeButton = window.add ('button', undefined, 'Close');
    window.cancelElement = closeButton

    window.center();
    window.show();
    }

    function saveSettings (Identity, Fixture) {
    var file = '~/Documents/Read and write text102323210.txt';
    var str = read (file);
    var arr = str.split('\n');
    var c = Math.floor(arr[0]);

    if (Identity[0] == 'N') {
        if (Identity[1] == 'F') {
            arr[c+1] = Fixture;
            arr[0] = c + 1;
            str = arr.toString().replace(/,/g, '\n');
            write (file, str);           
            UI();}}

        if (Identity[0] == 'R') {
        if (Identity[1] == 'F') {
            if (Identity[2] == c) {
                arr[c] = '';
                arr[0] = c - 1;
                str = arr.toString().replace(/,/g, '\n');
                write (file, str);           
                UI();}}}
                    if (Identity[2] < c) {
                        for ( i = 0; i <= c - Identity[2]; i++)
                            arr[Identity[2]] = arr[Identity[2]+1];
                        arr[c] = '';
                        arr[0] = c - 1;
                        str = arr.toString().replace(/,/g, '\n');
                        write (file, str);           
                        UI();}}

    function loadSettings (Identity) {
    var file = '~/Documents/Read and write text102323210.txt';
    var str = read (file);
    var arr = str.split('\n');
    
    if (Identity[0] == 'I')
        if (Identity[1] == 'F')
            if (Identity[2] == 0)
                return Math.floor(arr[Identity[2]]);
                    else return arr[Identity[2]];}

    function read (filePath) {
    var file = new File (filePath);    
    file.open('r');
    file.encoding = 'UTF8';
    var text = file.read();
    file.close(); 
    return text;}

    function write (filePath, textContent) {  
    var file = new File( filePath );   
    file.open('w');
    file.encoding = 'UTF8';
    file.write( textContent );
    file.close();}`
```

Add/remove buttons work fine. When I click on close button instead of closing the window it    starts to remove folders, sometimes one other times two at the time. When no more folders are left then it closes. Topright corner close button deletes all folders at once.

I've tried: window and palette, window acts the same, palette just goes bannans.
turning ...{closeButton: true});, on and off.

```
closeButton.onClick = function () {window.close();}
closeButton.onClick = function () {window.close(); break;}
closeButton.onClick = function () {window.close(); return;}
closeButton.onClick = function () {window.close(); return 1;}
closeButton.onClick = function () {window.close(); exit();}
```

..also tried calling a funktion and returning window.close;

..it's like it just continiues and keeps on clicking on remove buttons :(

Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Could you describe what the script supposed to do? Right now, as far as I can tell (you're calling a new `UI()` from the `UI()` — it can caused the glitches), it looks as you want to a 'palette' window, not a 'dialog' window. A palette can stay on the screen constantly and do the stuff until you close it somehow. Not like a 'dialog window' which works only after you close it.

Comment: Well, the script loads files paths from multiple folders (up to 10, for now), then it sorts ‘em after “tag” name, then it creates a template of same size, then it stacks the files as layers in the right order while applying exposure adjustment layer one by one, then it converts mode from 32 to 16 bit and saves as psd. That’s what it does atm, but I’m planning to add many more options to it. It converts invisible (overexposed) .exr 32 bit files to visible 16 bit .psd files that can be worked with. 3D animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the script does without a sample of input data and some description. But it looks for me like you trying to keep the window on the screen after you click 'Add' button and you're calling the `new Widnow()` for this. It can be a problem for 'dialog window'. There are a 'palette window' that is staying on the screen all the time until you close it manually.

Here is the example how it could be done as a 'palette':

```
#targetengine 'session'

var window = new Window ('palette', 'Settings', undefined, {closeButton: true});
window.orientation = 'column';

var iFolderC = loadSettings (['I','F',0]);
for (var i = 1; i <= iFolderC; i++) {
    eval('var ' + "iFolder" + i + " = loadSettings (['I','F'," + i + "]);");
}

var inputGroup = window.add ('group');
inputGroup.add('panel', undefined, 'Input Folders', {borderStyle:'raised'});
inputGroup.orientation = 'column';

for (i = 1; i <= iFolderC; i++) {
    eval('var ' + "inputFolder" + i + "= inputGroup.add ('group');");
    eval("inputFolder" + i + ".add('panel', [0, 0, 300, 20], iFolder"+ i +", {borderStyle:'raised'});");
    eval('var ' + "removeButton" + i + "= inputFolder" + i + ".add ('button', undefined, 'Remove');");
}

var newFolder = inputGroup.add ('group');

var newIFolder = newFolder.add('edittext',[0, 0, 300, 20]);

var addButton =  newFolder.add ('button', undefined, 'Add');
addButton.onClick = function () {
    saveSettings (['N', 'F', 0], newIFolder.text);
    newIFolder.text = ''; // reset input field
}

for (i = 1; i <= iFolderC; i++) {
    eval("removeButton" + i + ".onClick = function() {saveSettings (['R', 'F'," + i + "], '');}");
}

var closeButton = window.add ('button', undefined, 'Close');
closeButton.onClick = function () {
    window.close();
}

window.center();
window.show();

function saveSettings (Identity, Fixture) {
    var file = '~/Documents/Read and write text102323210.txt';
    var str = read (file);
    var arr = str.split('\n');
    var c = Math.floor(arr[0]);

    if (Identity[0] == 'N') {
        if (Identity[1] == 'F') {
            arr[c+1] = Fixture;
            arr[0] = c + 1;
            str = arr.toString().replace(/,/g, '\n');
            write (file, str);
        }
    }

    if (Identity[0] == 'R') {
        if (Identity[1] == 'F') {
            if (Identity[2] == c) {
                arr[c] = '';
                arr[0] = c - 1;
                str = arr.toString().replace(/,/g, '\n');
                write (file, str);
            }
        }
    }

    if (Identity[2] < c) {
        for (i = 0; i <= c - Identity[2]; i++) arr[Identity[2]] = arr[Identity[2]+1];
        arr[c] = '';
        arr[0] = c - 1;
        str = arr.toString().replace(/,/g, '\n');
        write (file, str);
    }
}

function loadSettings (Identity) {
    var file = '~/Documents/Read and write text102323210.txt';
    var str = read (file);
    var arr = str.split('\n');

    if (Identity[0] == 'I') {
        if (Identity[1] == 'F') {
            if (Identity[2] == 0) {
                return Math.floor(arr[Identity[2]]);
            }
            else {
                return arr[Identity[2]];
            }
        }
    }
}

function read (filePath) {
    var file = new File (filePath);
    file.open('r');
    file.encoding = 'UTF8';
    var text = file.read();
    file.close();
    return text;
}

function write (filePath, textContent) {
    var file = new File( filePath );
    file.open('w');
    file.encoding = 'UTF8';
    file.write( textContent );
    file.close();
}
```

I'm not sure if the code does exactly what you want, it's just a half-working example of the 'palette' concept. The main point: you don't have to recreate the window every time you click 'Add' button. And if you need to change the window after click the 'Add' button it can be done as well without closing and creating the window anew.

Comment: Wow mate :))),

I've given up on the UI, but now I'll give it a go again.

THANK YOU SOOOOOO MUCH.

...meanwhile I've be reading a bit mostly [ScriptUI 2.8 Tutorial](https://fotozcech.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/scriptui-2-8.pdf) and sotra found out that I need use addEventListerner for what I'm planing to acheive. Cuz my UI (once finished, haha) gonna have many buttons and several tabs.

Comment: ... I should have responded earlier. I'm very sorry for that. 

Thanks again and your main point has been stored in memory block!! I wasn't aware that I could keep the window open while clicking on buttons etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've be reading a bit mostly [ScriptUI 2.8 Tutorial](https://fotozcech.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/scriptui-2-8.pdf) and sotra found out that I need use addEventListerner for what I'm planning to achieve.

```
var w = new Window ("dialog");
var buttongroup = w.add ("group");
var panel1 = buttongroup.add ("panel", undefined, "Buttons");
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 panel1.add ("button", undefined, "Button " + i);
var panel2 = buttongroup.add ("panel", undefined, "Knoppen");
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 panel2.add ("button", undefined, "Button " + i);
buttongroup.addEventListener('click', button_pressed);
function button_pressed (e)
 {
 if (e.target.type == "button")
 $.writeln (e.target.text + " from panel " + e.target.parent.text);
 }
w.show();
```

Cuz my UI (once finished, haha) gonna have many buttons and several tabs. I've bitten more then I could chew for my very first javascript, ever :D. Also I've sorta given up on dynamic variables/statments "eval()" it's just waste of time! (For me at this stage, at least) However, it would be nice if I could make the buttons dynamic. This can be done in a loop as in the example above.

The main script is partially done and it works :D, I’ll be adding to it for a while to come, tho. But the main function is done and it saves me hours of tedious work every week.

Thanks for your replies guys and best regards

Comment: Ok. But it's a bit weird. EventListeners usually are using to handle keyboard events or some tricky events like 'after open document', 'before save document', 'resize a frame with a mouse', etc. You don't need them (usually) to handle the standard 'Click' event. Though the both approach should work fine, I think.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't use weird abbreviations, salutations or content in your posts.